# MVC Core, Web Sockets and threading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, websocket, asp.net-core

I am working on a solution that uses web socket protocol to notify client (web browser) when some event happened on the server (MVC Core web app). I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets nuget.

Here is my client-side code:

```
  $(function () {
    var socket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:61019/data/openSocket");

    socket.onopen = function () {
      $(".socket-status").css("color", "green");
    }

    socket.onmessage = function (message) {
      $("body").append(document.createTextNode(message.data));
    }

    socket.onclose = function () {
      $(".socket-status").css("color", "red");
    }
  });
```

When this view is loaded the socket request is immediately sent to the MVC Core application. Here is the controller action:

```
[Route("data")]
public class DataController : Controller
{
    [Route("openSocket")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult OpenSocket()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            WebSocket socket = HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync().Result;

            if (socket != null && socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                while (!HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    var response = string.Format("Hello! Time {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString());
                    var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);

                    Task.Run(() => socket.SendAsync(new System.ArraySegment<byte>(bytes),
                        WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None));
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);
                }
            }
        }
        return new StatusCodeResult(101);
    }
}
```

This code works very well. WebSocket here is used exclusively for sending and doesn't receive anything. The problem, however, is that the while loop keeps holding the DataController thread until cancellation request is detected.

Web socket here is bound to the HttpContext object. As soon as HttpContext for the web request is destroyed the socket connection is immediately closed.

Question 1: Is there any way that socket can be preserved outside of the controller thread?
I tried putting it into a singleton that lives in the MVC Core Startup class that is running on the main application thread. Is there any way to keep the socket open or establish connection again from within the main application thread rather than keep holding the controller thread with a while loop? 
Even if it is deemed to be OK to hold up controller thread for socket connection to remain open, I cannot think of any good code to put inside the OpenSocket's while loop. What do you think about having a manual reset event in the controller and wait for it to be set inside the while loop within OpenSocket action?

Question 2: If it is not possible to separate HttpContext and WebSocket objects in MVC, what other alternative technologies or development patterns can be utilized to achieve socket connection reuse? If anyone thinks that SignalR or a similar library has some code allowing to have socket independent from HttpContext, please share some example code. If someone thinks there is a better alternative to MVC for this particular scenario, please provide an example, I do not mind switching to pure ASP.NET or Web API, if MVC does not have capabilities to handle independent socket communication.

Question 3: The requirement is to keep socket connection alive or be able to reconnect until explicit timeout or cancel request by the user. The idea is that some independent event happens on the server that triggers established socket to send data. 
If you think that some technology other than web sockets would be more useful for this scenario (like HTML/2 or streaming), could you please describe the pattern and frameworks you would use?

P.S. Possible solution would be to send AJAX requests every second to ask if there was new data on the server. This is the last resort.

Comment: `SignalR` looks very promising, but can't provide any code for you as don't know a lot about it.

Answer (score 9):

After lengthy research I ended up going with a custom middleware solution. Here is my middleware class:

```
        public class SocketMiddleware
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, SocketMiddleware> _activeConnections = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, SocketMiddleware>();
        private string _packet;

        private ManualResetEvent _send = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private ManualResetEvent _exit = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public SocketMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public void Send(string data)
        {
            _packet = data;
            _send.Set();
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {    
                string connectionName = context.Request.Query["connectionName"]);
                if (!_activeConnections.Any(ac => ac.Key == connectionName))
                {
                    WebSocket socket = await context.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync();
                    if (socket == null || socket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                    {
                        await _next.Invoke(context);
                        return;
                    }
                    Thread sender = new Thread(() => StartSending(socket));
                    sender.Start();

                    if (!_activeConnections.TryAdd(connectionName, this))
                    {
                        _exit.Set();
                        await _next.Invoke(context);
                        return;
                    }

                    while (true)
                    {
                        WebSocketReceiveResult result = socket.ReceiveAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1]), CancellationToken.None).Result;
                        if (result.CloseStatus.HasValue)
                        {
                            _exit.Set();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    SocketHandler dummy;
                    _activeConnections.TryRemove(key, out dummy);
                }
            }

            await _next.Invoke(context);

            string data = context.Items["Data"] as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
            {
                string name = context.Items["ConnectionName"] as string;
                SocketMiddleware connection = _activeConnections.Where(ac => ac.Key == name)?.Single().Value;
                if (connection != null)
                {
                    connection.Send(data);
                }
            }
        }

        private void StartSending(WebSocket socket)
        {
            WaitHandle[] events = new WaitHandle[] { _send, _exit };
            while (true)
            {
                if (WaitHandle.WaitAny(events) == 1)
                {
                    break;
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_packet))
                {
                    SendPacket(socket, _packet);
                }
                _send.Reset();
            }
        }

        private void SendPacket(WebSocket socket, string packet)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(packet);
            ArraySegment<byte> segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);
            Task.Run(() => socket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None));
        }
    }
```

This middleware is going to run on every request. When Invoke is called it checks if it is a web socket request. If it is, the middleware checks if such connection was already opened and if it wasn't, the handshake is accepted and the middleware adds it to the dictionary of connections. It's important that the dictionary is static so that it is created only once during application lifetime.

Now if we stop here and move up the pipeline, HttpContext will eventually get destroyed and, since the socket is not properly encapsulated, it will be closed too. So we must keep the middleware thread running. It is done by asking socket to receive some data.

You may ask why we need to receive anything if the requirement is just to send? The answer is that it is the only way to reliably detect client disconnecting. HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested works only if you constantly send within the while loop. If you need to wait for some server event on a WaitHandle, cancellation flag is never true. I tried to wait for HttpContext.RequestAborted.WaitHandle as my exit event, but it is never set either. So we ask socket to receive something and if that something sets CloseStatus.HasValue to true, we know that client disconnected. If we receive something else (client side code is unsafe) we will ignore it and start receiving again.

Sending is done in a separate thread. The reason is the same, it's not possible to detect disconnection if we wait on the main middleware thread. To notify the sender thread that client disconnected we use _exit synchronization variable. Remember, it is fine to have private members here since SocketMiddleware instances are saved in a static container.

Now, how do we actually send anything with this set up? Let's say an event occurs on the server and some data becomes available. For simplicity sake, lets assume this data arrives inside normal http request to some controller action. SocketMiddleware will run for every request, but since it is not web socket request, _next.Invoke(context) is called and the request reaches controller action which may look something like this:

```
[Route("ProvideData")]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProvideData(string data, string connectionName)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionName))
    {
        HttpContext.Items.Add("ConnectionName", connectionName);
        HttpContext.Items.Add("Data", data);
    }
        return Ok();
}
```

Controller populates Items collection which is used to share data between components. Then the pipeline returns to the SocketMiddleware again where we check whether there is anything interesting inside the context.Items. If there is we select respective connection from the dictionary and call its Send() method that sets data string and sets _send event and allows single run of the while loop inside the sender thread.

And voila, we a have socket connection that sends on server side event. This example is very primitive and is there just to illustrate the concept. Of course, to use this middleware you will need to add the following lines in your Startup class before you add MVC:

```
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseMiddleware<SocketMiddleware>();
```

Code is very strange and hopefully we'll be able to write something much nicer when SignalR for dotnetcore is finally out. Hopefully this example will be useful for someone. Comments and suggestions are welcome.

Comment: So you built this helper class, but you still need 2 threads to keep running for every open socket. My main concern that we can run out of available threads if number of open sockets increased. Did you do any research/load testing to proof that this not will happen? Number of connected sockets may be easily get to hundreds. Will it still work? Thanks